# GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome cannot be assigned

Tags: swift, game-center

I'm making a turn based iOS game in Swift and before the `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData` method is called it is required that I set the `matchOutcome` property of each participant.  But this first line of code (below) in the function results in an error `Cannot assign a value of type 'GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome' to a value of type 'GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome!'`

```
func endGame()
{
    self.currentMatch.participants[0].matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome.Won
    self.currentMatch.endMatchInTurnWithMatchData(gameData, completionHandler: {(error) -> Void in gameData = NSData()})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling the participant out of the participants array first, like so:

```
GKTurnBasedParticipant *part0 = match.participants[0];
part0.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!! I had spent a long time figuring this out.  The thing that confused me before trying your method was that the participants are of type 'AnyObject' when listed in the match but if you pull them out into a new variable and convert them to 'GKTurnBasedParticipant' like you said it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! You might consider accepting this as the correct answer then. Thanks!